# Visual C++ application deployment that involves openCV: Proper Guideine needed

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, dll, deployment, opencv3.0

I have written large amount code using Visual C++ on Visual Studio IDE(VS 2015 Enterprise).My application depends heavily on openCV(x64-vc14). It runs perfectly on my computer. But when I tried to deploy using install shield limited(in debug build mode) to another computer, it shows the .exe file depends many .dll files. I had gone through google, found about dependency walker but when I run dependency walker it gives a dependency list with thousands of .dll files. It's time consuming manual process to copy each of the dll files from my computer and add it in the directory of the application. Is there any other better way to do this automatically? Is there anything I am missing during the building process or in the project property set up? I need a guideline because, in future my application will be even bigger and might also depend on more dll files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't deploy debug builds, they depend on the debug version of the CRT and that is not meant to be redistributed (or maybe you're not even allowed to, I don't know, not a lawyer).
Instead build the release version and install the 'Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2015' on the target machine - Installshield should have that as a Prerequisite. For OpenCV you'll have to instruct Installshield to get all dlls needed. Either manually, or by having it scan for dependencies (though afaik then it might include way more than needed).

Comment: Thank you very much. I built my application in release mode. My application runs smoothly on the target computer because I installed Visual C++ Redistributable package. I still have to transfer openCV "opencv_world310.dll" (it is eligible for redistribution) along with my application. Could you please share me a way to embed that dll with the .exe or with the Install shield ?

Comment: Add it as a 'Component' in Installshield